# Deno - access web apis

Tags: javascript, deno, browser-api

I am bundling my Deno code for the web using `deno bundle` and I know the browser has `RTCPeerConnection` from the WebRTC API which I would like to use.

I thought Deno was aiming to have web compatibility, so I don't see why WebRTC is not planned to be implemented.

But since it isn't at the moment, how can I tell Deno to trust that this global variable exists and to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `deno bundle` will actually run fine for many web APIs that are supported by the Deno language.

My temporary solution for other apis such as `crypto` is the following:

```
declare crypto: any;
```

[This article](https://blog.logrocket.com/deno-1-0-what-you-need-to-know/#:%7E:text=Compiling%20and%20bundling) might be useful to look at too (see the 'Compiling and bundling' section).

---

EDIT: in order to support a wide variety of environments, dependency injection can be a great solution in many cases.